# "Player A" was swapped for "Player B". Who's in the game now?

Tags: american-english

When using the phrase

> Joe was swapped for Jack

does that mean Joe was in the game, and he was replaced with Jack, or did Joe replace Jack in the game, and is now the one in the game?

I heard this phrase while listening to a baseball game. The commentator made the comment

> Player A was swapped for Player B on first base

to mean that Player B was replaced by Player A, and it struck me wrong. However, thinking about it, it seems like it can make sense either way.

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of the word “swap”? Why do you think it has a special meaning in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Player A was swapped for player B" simply means that A and B exchanged positions and status. Whichever was in before is now out, but one cannot reliably tell which is which without more context. Particularly in the informal, quick world of verbal sports reporting, this could be used either way, and the better known player might well be mentioned first which ever is coming in or going out.

Now if it was said that "Player A was swapped in for player B" then the reader or listener knows that player A is going I and B si going out.

With no other context it is perhaps more likely in the original form, that A (the first mentioned) is going in and B is coming out, but one simply cannot be sure.